# User types student name and by ajax I want all the data of student to be shown by name. User may not know id, like facebook friend search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

How to uniquely identify a record by typing non unique item in a text box. For example using autocomplete I type student name and it suggests any three names, now how should I make sure which one is correct. I have student id in database table but I want to make it more user friendly so I do not want to work with id in front end.

Comment: Essentially, you can't. You need some combination of unique items to make it identifiable to the user. 

For instance, if there are three Steves, how would the system know which Steve is being referred to without more information?

You do not need to necessarily display the ID in the front end. What are you trying to achieve? Viewing records or updating them? Or adding new records?

Comment: Using ajax user type student name and I want all the data of student to be shown to user just by name or + by his school name. User may not know id and it is shown in facebook friend search almost accurately. There is no option for typing id in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal solves this problem by appending the id to the value so it would look like: James Kirk [10]
Then parse the value by pulling the last [] pair's contents. But obviously that's not what you want to do. It's dirty and doesn't look good to the user.

I solved this issue by using a jquery autocomplete control with a hidden form item that stores the id and the visible form item that stores the user readable value.

Full Control html with jquery ui

```
<div class="form-item type-autocomplete_ajax name-employer">
    <label for="employer"> Employer          </label>
    <input type="autocomplete_ajax" name="employer-label" maxlength="60" size="30" value="EAS" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="employer" value="14">
    <div class="description">Begin typing to see your options. You may add your own value if the desired value is not available</div>
    <script>
      $('.name-employer input[name="employer-label"]').autocomplete({source: function( request, response )
    {
      var form_id = "patient_info_form";
      var form_item = "employer";
      $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/options?term=" + request.term,
        dataType:"json"
      })
        .done(function(list)
        {
          $(".ui-autocomplete-loading").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
          response(list);
        })
        .fail(function()
        {
          $(".ui-autocomplete-loading").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
          list = [{"label": "No results found", "value": 0, "id": 0}];
          response(list);
        })
    },select: function (event, ui)
    {
      if (ui.item.id != 0)
      {
        $('.name-employer input[name="employer-label"]').val(ui.item.label);
        $('.name-employer input[name="employer"]').val(ui.item.value);
      }
      return false;
    }, focus: function (event, ui) {
      if (event.keyCode == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
      $('.name-employer input[name="employer-label"]').val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    }});$('.name-employer input[name="employer-label"]').focusout(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "")
      {
        $('.name-employer input[name="employer"]').val("");
      }
    });    </script>
  </div>
```

Notice two inputs. The first is an autocoplete that jquery ui builds. The xecond is just a hidden input that stores the "key" unique id value that the user doesn't need to see.

Then on submit ignore the autocomplet value and just check the hidden value.

Comment: All well, but I want complete rid of id. I can provide you with employer name, employer city or employer company but no id anymore. Such as student name and student school name and then uniquely efficient way to pop up efficient/correct student. In addition we have to deal with new student entry and old student already entered in other table.

Comment: The hidden field doesn't have to be an id. It can be any information you want. Ultimately it should be the primary key in your database.